# How to reshape dataframe with multi year data in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I believe my question can be solved with a loop but I haven't been able to create such. I have a data sample which looks like this
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kncyw.png)

And I would like to have dataframe that would be organised by the year:
[result data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E8pF.png)

I tried pivot-function by creating a year column with df['year'] = df.index.year and then reshaping with pivot but it will populate only the first year column because of the index.

I have managed to do this type of reshaping manually but with several years of data it is time consuming solution. Here is the example code for manual solution:

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame()
mydata2 = pd.DataFrame()
mydata3 = pd.DataFrame()
mydata1['1'] = df['data'].iloc[160:664]
mydata2['2'] = df['data'].iloc[2769:3273]
mydata3['3'] = df['data'].iloc[5583:6087]
mydata1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
mydata2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
mydata3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
mydata = pd.concat([mydata1, mydata2, mydata3],axis=1, ignore_index=True)
mydata.columns = ['78','88','00','05']
```

Comment: How did you get the [160:664], [2769:3273], and [5583:6087]? also, these ['78','88','00','05']?

Comment: If you'd like people to be able to properly help you with your code, do not post your sample data as a picture as it makes it much more difficult to import it into a test code and run your program. Take the time to write your data input and output out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I think I understood what you were asking for from your question, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Basically, you want to reshape your current `pandas.DataFrame` using a pivot. I set up a sample dataset and solved the problem in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

#test set
df = pd.DataFrame({'Index':['2.1.2000','3.1.2000','3.1.2001','4.1.2001','3.1.2002','4.1.2002'],
                   'Value':[100,101,110,111,105,104]})

#create a year column for yourself
#by splitting on '.' and selecting year element.
df['Year'] = df['Index'].str.split('.', expand=True)[2]

#pivot your table
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns='Year', values='Value')

#now, in my pivoted test set there should be unwanted null values showing up so
#we can apply another function that drops null values in each column without losing values in other columns
pivot = pivot.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
```

#### Result on my end

```
| Year | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 |
|------|------|------|------|
| 0    | 100  | 110  | 105  |
| 1    | 101  | 111  | 104  |
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm! So I was on the right track with the pivot function but I only got the first column populated and rest of the columns had NaN. The lambda function I don't fully understand what it does but it worked. I thought that the problem was with the pd.pivot_table that it left the index as it was and that's why it only populated the first column.

Comment: One more question. After I try to look at individual columns like df['2001'].head() I receive an error: TypeError: an integer is required.

Comment: Glad to be of help, if my solution and advice worked please select my solution as the accepted answer, thank you again!

Comment: @Jr Decker, error on my part. Run `df[['2001']].head()` if you want to view the first 5 rows of your new DataFrame. The dtype of the column is already str. Anyway, glad to help!